# Modify the non-editable class in Android Studio

Tags: android, class, fragmentstatepageradapter

As I can change a class, it come in android packages, which is not highly recommended but I need it.
If someone can help me how to write this class that seems to block when I write.[image]

Comment: You cannot modify that class. You can fork it, by copying the source code to your project, putting in your own Java package, modifying it as you see fit, and using your fork.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it because when you publish your app, the code of this class will come from the Android system on the device it is running.

The biggest hack you can do is to access package private variables in Android system by creating your class in such package. But even then there are some security rules that can block you.

Comment: So I need to modify this class so that all the fragments that are not visible in this class are based on this link. As I can solve it.  [link](http://doublenegative.com/fragment-state-restoration-and-the-fragmentstatepageradapter/)